# iOS storyboard: I can't specify a imageview as the parent view for a imageview

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I'm trying to add an imageview as an imageview childview，but I can't do it.

First I add a imageview A, than I add a new imageview B, I want A become the parent  view of B, but I can't do it.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please explain your question clearly. What actually you are trying to achieve.

Comment: do you want to add image within parent image or you just want to put image  upon parent image?

Comment: i want to add imageview within parent imageview

Comment: You can do it by writing code or directly using storyboard

Comment: i use storyboard, i know i can solve the problem by using code,i don't know why i cannot make it by storyboard

Comment: Exactly, i tried as given in your image and its working here so whats the issue you are getting there?

Comment: i don't why i cannot make it ,Can you give me a screenshot ? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add another uiimageview instance as subview via storyboard. The only possible solution for you (if you still want to do so) add your view hierarchy through your code.

You can create the following hierarchy to imitate child-parent relationship via storyboard:

1. drag uiview to your scene. (view1)
2. drag another view inside first one (view2)
3. add uiimageview to every view (view1, view2)

now your relations will look like:

view1(parent)->view2(child). and every view will have uiimageview subview.
Take a look at screenshot

[image]

Hope this helps.